# PHP proc_open return value is always equal to 127

Tags: php

I am facing really big issue with PHP. **I am creating PHP application, that will "use" another application.** I want to **redirect input and output**. I'm using `proc_open` to do so. **File `gsqasm` is inside `/var/www/http`.** The working directory is the same, so **`./gsqasm` should do the trick**. Too bad, that it doesn't. **Return code always is equal to 127**. After googling for a while, **i figured out that 127 means that file couldn't be found**. Then, to make sure, I checked `/tmp/error-output.txt` file. It's content was:

```
sh: 1: gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: /var/www/http/gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: /var/www/http/gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: /var/www/http/gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: ./gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: ./gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: .gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: /var/www/http/gsqasm: not found
sh: 1: /var/www/http/gsqasm: not found
```

As you can see, I tried maaany times, without luck. I am propably missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array(
        "pipe",
        "r"
    ), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array(
        "pipe",
        "w"
    ), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array(
        "file",
        "/tmp/error-output.txt",
        "a"
    ) // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array(
    'some_option' => 'aeiou'
);

passthru('echo $PWD');
echo '<br>';
$process = proc_open('./gsqasm', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (!isset($_POST['input'])) {
    echo "Input is empty.";
}

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/erroroutput.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], $_POST['input']);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

How do I change this code, to execute application correctly, while redirecting streams? This is not code designed to run on production, It's some quick and dirty thing that will get solid after some time.

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions of the gsqasm program?  Can you provide this in your question  `ls -lathF | grep gsqasm`

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  88K Mar 25 07:07 gsqasm*` is the output.

Comment: In the same directory you just ran the ls from please run `pwd` and provide the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit code 127 does in fact mean "command not found". The file may exist at `/var/www/http/gsqasm`, but you're telling it to look at `/tmp/gsqasm`. You have `$cwd`, the working directory that the command will be run from, set to `/tmp`. The command is also prepended by `./`, telling it to look in the (incorrectly provided) current working directory for `gsqasm`.

To fix this, you can change `$cwd` to be `null` (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), this defaults to the script's directory) or an absolute path to the program's location, which you said is also `/var/www/http`. You also could change `./` to include that absolute path. Either of those three options will work, I personally would recommend the first because of simplicity.

Comment: As you can see in logs, I tried to use absolute path with no luck. What has CWD to do with this...?